# Is Blender going to optimize RTX cores?

Tags: rendering, scripting

Right now blender can be used with RTX cards but they are not as optimized and are not using the RTX cores to there full extent. Will this change, am i wrong? If anyone has info on how this new tech works with blender help out.

Answer (score 2):

There is now an option to render using OptiX, which renders in Cycles on the GPU using the acceleration of RT cores in the latest RTX GPUs. Most recently in the Blender 2.92 update, OptiX has been modified to render with both the CPU and RTX GPU combined.